# IWin32Window in WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have an excel AddIn which exposes IWin32Window as it's main UI.
I want to show a WPF window that uses this as it's parent.

How do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) to parent the WPF window appropriately:

```
var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(theWpfWindow);
helper.Owner = win32Window.Handle;

theWpfWindow.Show(); // This is now parented appropriately
```

Comment: I have this: System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window (note, it is NOT namespace).
MainHostWindow host = new MainHostWindow();
            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(host);
            helper.Owner = this._mainWindow.Handle;    

host.Owner is NULL

Comment: @Pacman: host.Owner will stay null - you just set the interop helper as I showed, and it should parent it appropriately.  If you want it modal, use ShowDialog()...

Comment: What is I want to make the Owner Window Disabled:
host.Owner.IsEnabled = false ?

Comment: @Pacman: You're trying to disable Excel's main window?  You won't be able to do that from an extension - better to just use ShowDialog() to open your window modally, which will prevent the user from interacting with the host until you close your window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a WindowInteropHelper, like shown here: [IWin32Window Owner For WPF Window](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/01/16/iwin32window-owner-for-wpf-window.aspx)