# Writing a Resharper ContextAction that takes user input

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-6.1, resharper-plugins

I want to create a Resharper ContextAction which takes a string from the user. How can I create a box with an input field whose entered value can be processed inside the ExecutePsiTransation method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use standard WPF/Windows forms dialogs. For Windows forms use Show/ShowDialog overload that takes IWin32Window instance. For WPF see [IWin32Window in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543509/iwin32window-in-wpf) . Get instance of IWin32Window  via Shell.Instance.GetComponent().MainWindow . And do it not from ExecutePsiTransation, but from ExecuteBeforeProgressAndTransaction method.

Comment: Darn, you're consistently beating me to questions :)

Comment: It's not good idea to get user input inside ExecutePsiTransation.